# ReactJS: Maximum update depth exceeded when fetching data from local-storage token

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting the above error on the following code. Will anyone help me find out what could be wrong with this code? Thanks

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    setUserData(user);
  });
```

This is the `getCurrentUser` function

```
export function getCurrentUser() {
  try {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
    return jwtDecode(jwt);
  } catch (ex) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be very cautious while using `useEffect`.

Below is what you have used in your implementation. Which is also the problem why the error.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    setUserData(user);
  });
```

To understand what exactly happening just a background of `useEffect`. When `useEffect` is being used without any dependencies it'll execute every time the component gets rendered. Please have a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks) for more info.

So in this case in `useEffect` you are trying to update the state of the component which will cause the component to re-render, as discussed again `useEffect` will get called again state gets updated and the loop goes on.

```
setUserData() -> component re-render -> setUserData() -> component re-render -> setUserData() -> component re-render ....the cycle goes on
```

So ideally you should be getting the current user details only once after the component mounted and this can be done by passing `[]` as dependency to `useEffect` as below

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    setUserData(user);
  }, []);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this

```
    useEffect(() => {
    function getData() {
         const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
         setUserData(user);
    }   
    getData()
    },[]);
```

Comment: not sure if `async` is applicable here..rem i am fetching data from local storage not an api